# How to start a GUI application from cron?

Tags: firefox, java, cron

I need to run a Java applet from a Firefox. The problem is, I need to run this Firefox from a cron. If I run from the command line and its work fine, but when put the command in the cron it failed:

```
*/1 * * * * firefox http://domain.com/iqms/packetloss/iqmspacket2.html
```

Comment: You can use [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)'s java library if you need more functions than just opening it.

Comment: You can also use [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) with python, which is easier for scripts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found this answer i am looking for addition to oli's :

After a few search, I found that i need to run as a valid user instead from root.

```
* * * * * su fadabi -c "DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/bin/firefox -new-window x.com/iqms/packetloss/iqmspacket2.html";
```

tq

Comment: This helped, thanks a lot! Just a note: full path to Firefox is mandatory, I didn't realise that and it didn't work

Comment: It would be easier to run the command from the user's personal crontab. Edit the user's crontab by running `crontab -e` without sudo.

Answer (score 42):

Cron runs in an environment that knows nothing about the display manager (`$DISPLAY` isn't set). Your terminal window that you've been testing in has this set for it. If you tried it in a "real" terminal, or over SSH, you'd see it break.

If you've only got one X server running, just specifying the display might work:

```
* * * * *    DISPLAY=:0 firefox ...
```

You could probably put more effort into working out what display it's sitting under rather than assuming it's `:0` but that will probably work most of the time.

If you just need to reload something a lot, look at [Tab Auto Reload](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/tab-auto-reload/) or similar Firefox plugins.

Comment: I found this answer but still does not start the firefox. After a few search, I found that i need to run as a valid user instead from root. * * * * * "DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/bin/firefox -new-window http://x.com/iqms/packetloss/iqmspacket2.html"

Comment: @fadabiNawi An easier way of managing that would be to install the cron line into the correct user's crontab. Log in as who you want, and `crontab -e`

Comment: you just read my mind 6 years before

Comment: This seemed to work on Wayland for me.

Answer (score 7):

For me `DISPLAY=:0` didn't work. When I check `echo $DISPLAY` in the terminal it returned `1`.  So `DISPLAY=:1` worked for me. (on Ubuntu 20.04)