# Cannot schedule GUI program

Tags: 16.04, cron

Have been trying to create a daily task to open GUI program (for the sake of argument say it is `firefox`) using `crontab` but I am not succeeding.  At least I can't tell as no message is sent to terminal.

I have followed the instructions from these sites:

- [CronHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)
- [How do I set up a Cron job?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job)

to no avail.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/514167/how-to-start-a-gui-application-from-cron/514172#514172
Refer to this, You will find your answer.

Comment: @RohittVashishtha I just tried this:  

`sudo crontab -u username -r` to delete what I had.  

Then `sudo crontab -u username -e` to create and edit a new `crontab` for `username`.  At the end of the filed I added:

`52 13   * * *  DISPLAY=:0 firefox`.  I added this at 13:50 my time but at 13:52 nothing happened.

Comment: While I was waiting for an answer, something interesting happened. The script setup through `crontab` actually ran!   It turns out that it seems to to be using the time of day without considering the summer time.  That is, it is taking the time as a fixed time from UTC not considering that it is still summer time.  

The issue about not being able to install `gnome-schedule` still remains.  I recognise this is a different issue so I will be removing this from here and asking this in a different question.

Comment: So,... cron doesn't play nice with timezones, eh? Sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While waiting for an answer on why the `crontab` event was not running something interesting happened: the script setup through `crontab` actually ran! It turns out that it seems to to be using the time of day without considering the summer time. That is, it is taking the time as a fixed time from UTC not considering that it is still summer time.

As an example, the task that was setup as:

```
52 13 * * * /home/username/my_script.sh
```

actually ran at 14:52 (that is what the clock at the top right corner of my screen said).  Because we are still in summer time, I am concluding that `cron` actually looks at the system clock and ignores the fact that we have added one hour due to summer time.  Using @Rohitt Vashishtha words: *cron doesn't play nice with timezones*.