# Variable in bash via cron?

Tags: bash, cron

```
#!/bin/bash

ddd=$(date +%Y-%m -d "-1 month")
xmessage  -timeout 10 $ddd
```

If I try this simple script I get this to work fine from terminal but when I start this script via `cron` the variable is always empty? I have tried many different syntax but the result is the same. Works in Terminal but not from cron.

Comment: xmessage won't work in cron without a bit more preparation. Cron has a different environment than your terminal.

Comment: If you are not logged in there is no display where xmessage would be able to show. Try setting also the DISPLAY variable as you set ddd, before you call xmessage. Type `set | grep DISPLAY` to see what is your display (probably `DISPLAY=:0`). Use that line before calling xmessage, so it will know where to display.

Comment: ddd=$(date +%Y-%m) = Working and ddd=$(date +%Y-%m -d "-1 month") is not working :-(

Comment: Check `/var/log/syslog/`, it may contain more information on what cron is stumbling upon.

Answer (score 1):

`man date` says:

```bsh
SYNOPSIS
       date [OPTION]... [+FORMAT]
```

It should work either way, but you're on the safe side using `date` the way the manpage tells you:

```bsh
ddd=$(date -d "-1 month" +%Y-%m)
```

With a script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
ddd=$(date -d "-1 month" +%Y-%m)
xmessage -timeout 10 $ddd
```

and the cronjob line

```bsh
* * * * * DISPLAY=:0 /path/to/script.sh
```

it works very well on my system – see [How to start a GUI application from cron?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/514167/how-to-start-a-gui-application-from-cron) and [the Cron HowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto).

Comment: GNU tools are fairly flexible when it comes to ordering arguments and options. I'm inclined to think the DISPLAY variable was the problem

Comment: @muru I know, but the manpage tells me so. ;P Are you sure `FORMAT` is treated like an ordinary option? Either way, let me edit… I assumed `DISPLAY=:0` was the real problem here, so I added a working solution.

Comment: the manpage synopses always use the safest, simplest description. Whether the ordering matters is given in the extended description, and it doesn't particularly matter for `+FORMAT`