# cron can not start workrave

Tags: cron

Every now and then I close the program workrave. E.g. when I am watching a movie. Then I forget restarting it.

So, I want to restart it repeatedly. Somehow cron does not work. Following gives a summary:

ubuntu bionic (18.04)

i am a normal user (not root)

```
$ xhost
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
INET:localhost
INET6:localhost
SI:localuser:USERNAME

$ echo $DISPLAY
:0

$ crontab -l
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /usr/bin/workrave
```

when I open a tilix terminal and type `/usr/bin/workrave`, the program starts fine.

The command

```
* * * * * env DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/workrave
```

does not work either.

Comment: **1)** Does a simple `DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/workrave` work (as in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/514167/504066))? **2)** You know that `* * * * *` starts `workrave` _every single minute_, don't you?

Comment: @PerlDuck: 1) Yes it does work. 2) I know. Once the command works I will arrange frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your user name is `tiger` - just replace everywhere below the name with your real name of user. Create bash script in the home directory of your user:

```
touch /home/tiger/workrave.sh
```

Make the created script executable:

```
chmod +x /home/tiger/workrave.sh
```

Open the script in text editor, let it be nano for instance:

```
nano /home/tiger/workrave.sh
```

Insert into the script its content (don't forget to replace `tiger`):

```
#!/bin/bash
ifrun=$(pgrep -cxu tiger -f /usr/bin/workrave)
if [[ $ifrun == 0 ]] ;
then
    DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/workrave &
fi
```

Save changes and close text editor. Open crontab as `tiger`:

```
crontab -e
```

Add to end of crontab the line (don't forget to replace `tiger`):

```
*/1 * * * * /home/tiger/workrave.sh
```

Save and close crontab. Check if everything works (cron will run the script every minute). Setup time for the script execution. That's all.

**Remark.** The script executes workrave only if other its instances aren't running.

**UPDATE**

Script for testing purposes (replace `tiger`):

```
#!/bin/bash
DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/workrave 2>> /home/tiger/workrave-errors.log
```

Comment: Thanks for the code that checks whether workrave is running. The script works when I run it from the terminal. But it does not work through cron.  I am using budgie desktop on ubuntu. Each minute I see the workrave icon in its toolbar, but it goes away immediately. (it does not work in unity either)

Comment: I did. But I get the same behavior.